# Problems trying to retrieve information from txt file

Tags: java, string, text, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I'm stuck on one issue in my application. I have one text file that contains one piece of code that I need to retrieve to apply into one string variable. The problem is which is the best way to do this? I ran those samples below, but they are logically incorrect / incomplete. Take a look:

1. Reading through line:

   ```
   BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Node));

   String line = null;
   try {
       while( (line = bfr.readLine()) != null ){
           line.contentEquals("d.href");
           System.out.println(line);
       }
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. Reading through character:

   ```
   BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Node));
   int i = 0;
   try {
       while ((i = bfr.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) i;
            System.out.println(Character.toString(ch));
       }
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   };
   ```
3. Reading through Scanner:

   ```
   BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Node));
   BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Node));
   int wordCount = 0, totalcount = 0;
   Scanner s = new Scanner(googleNode);
   while (s.hasNext()) {
      totalcount++;
      if (s.next().contains("(?=d.href).*?(}=?)")) wordCount++;
   }
   System.out.println(wordCount+" "+totalcount);
   ```

With (1.) I'm having difficult to find `d.href` with contains the start of the code piece.
With (2.) I can't think or find one way to store `d.href` as string and retrieve the rest of information.
With (3.) I can correctly find `d.href` but I can't retrieve pieces of the txt.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: `Scanner` is likely to have problems since `next` will retrieve text separated by white-space. You may need to set the delimiter (with `setDelimiter`, or I think that's what it's called) or use `nextLine` instead of `next`.

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to do. Can you give sample input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answer of my question, I used scanner to read word by word in the text file. `.contains("window.maybeRedirectForGBV")` returns one boolean value, and `hasNext()` one string. Then, I stoped the query for my code stretch on the text file one word before I wanted and moved forward one more time to store the value of the next word on one string variable. From this point you only need to treat your string the way you want. Hope this help.

```
String stringSplit = null;
           Scanner s = new Scanner(Node);
           while (s.hasNext()) {

            if (s.next().contains("window.maybeRedirectForGBV")){
                stringSplit = s.next();
                break;
            }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*d\\.href([^=]*)=(.*)$");
// Groups:                                      1-----1 2--2
// Possibly spaces, "d.href", any characters not '=', the '=', any chars.

....
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String dHrefSuffix = m.group(1);
        String value = m.group(2);
        System.out.println(value);
        break;
    }
```

BufferedReader will do.

Comment: As far as I can read the code makes sense but I had no sucess with it, nothing went up on the console, even that I've changed to  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("d.href"); or Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a");

Comment: `match` does a match on the _entire_ line; `while (m.find())` is the alternative. This code should do with `.*\\b` (any characters, word boundary) instead of `\\s*` (spaces).

Comment: Thanks for you help, although I found another way to move forward in my case, check my answer please

Comment: Your solution should be faster, as pattern matching is notoriously slow. Always a joy to see someone tackle a problem. P.S. accept your own answer, to mark the question as solved.

Comment: Im waiting the 2 days delay to do this ;)) thanks for the support!!